# Mysql unable to select datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I'm trying to SELECT rows that matches datetime in my column. I have a table containing mDTS set as DATETIME (with no curly braces).
My table looks something like this:

| mID | mDTS | mDTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/08/2021 10:41:47 | 11/08/2021 10:41:47 |
| 2 | 12/08/2021 10:42:34 | 13/08/2021 10:42:34 |

```
CREATE TABLE tb_cyc (
  mID int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID cycle',
  mDTS datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Data inizio ciclo',
  mDTE datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Data fine ciclo',
  PRIMARY KEY (mID)
)
```

I'm trying to run the following query but it returns an empty set.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_cyc WHERE mDTS = '12/08/2021 10:42:34'
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_cyc WHERE mDTS LIKE '12/08/2021 10:42:34'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM tb_cyc WHERE mDTS = '12/08/2021 %'
```

But none of this seems to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are storing `datetime` in text datatype, you need to use string to date function like `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table tb_cyc`

Comment: I've updated the question to show the create table @ysth

Comment: You're using datetime datatype which is correct. Does mySQl actually return dates like `10/08/2021 10:41:47`?

Comment: That should be `Incorrect datetime value` , only if you are retrieving data from application and it convert to the format in your question

Comment: Yes, it does @SalmanA

Comment: @alessandro.todisco no, it actually doesn't.  whatever you are using to show the results is formatting the dates that way.  mysql expects and returns dates in ISO 8601 format: '2021-10-08 10:41:47'

Comment: You are right, DB forge was showing me the results in a different format. @ysth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the format of the date in WHERE clause:

```
WHERE mDTS = '2021-08-12 10:42:34'
```

What happens is that `mDTS` is a datetime; when compared with a string MySQL will treat the string as a date/time. The literal value `12/08/2021 10:42:34` will generate the following warning:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '12/08/2021 10:42:34' for column 'mDTS' at row 1
```

Comment: I've tried this: SELECT * FROM tb_cyc WHERE mDTS = '2021-08-12 10:42:34' and it works. I was looking for data using DB Forge, but the mDTS date was shown using slashes. I've tried opening the workbench and it returned the date using dashes

Comment: Your client is *formatting* the dates into human readable form, but in SQL you still need to use an unambiguous format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).

Comment: You are right, DB forge was showing me the results in a different format.